# How to save condition of button after closing app?

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

This is code of button:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                },120000);
            }
        });
```

I know that i need to create a sharedpreferences, but I didn't understand how to save condition of button which have a timer, because i know how to save without ussing handler.
How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want the timer to keep running when you close your app? Or to restart the timer with the certain amount of time that left when app resumes?

Comment: @ATP i want that timer keep running after closing app and after 2 mins some code will running (button will clickable, how in pasted code)

Comment: `sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("buttonEnabled",button.isEnabled()).commit();` and then `button.setEnabled(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("buttonEnabled",true);`

Comment: @ATP, can you do it in answer and using my code, cuz i tried to do it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use shared preference to save the state. Then, while creating the view of you fragment or activity, you should check the value you saved with shared preference and set the button state accordingly.

Permit me, please, to answer in Kotlin, maybe you or your IDE can do the translation.

To save your button state to shared preference, define this function;

```
fun setButtonState(context: Context, buttonEnabled: Boolean) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context).edit()
        .putBoolean("button", buttonEnabled).apply()
}
```

Then to get your saved button state from shared preference, define this function;

```
fun getButtonState(context: Context): Boolean {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context)
       .getBoolean("button", false)
}
```

In your **onCreateView** set the button state in accordance to your saved value.

```
val buttonEnabled = getButtonState(requireContext())
button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
button.isEnabled = buttonEnabled
```

Then toggle the saved state in shared preference like so:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
     button.isEnabled = false
     setButtonState(requireContext(), false)
     Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
         button.isEnabled = true
         setButtonState(requireContext(), true)
     }, 120000)
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hm, kotlin, well... I'll test

Comment: It isnt work://